# BGP multihoming and Multipath configuration

Tags: bgp, redundant-routes

Below is my architecture

[image]

Now, I have a 2 MX240 routers terminating diverse path circuits from 2 ISPs. Now, I would like to configure multipath BGP confiugration. If One ISP goes down totally on both routers, traffic will go out through other ISP connection. Is it possible to have such configuration in Juniper routers and any pointers on it would be helpful.

Comment: "_If One ISP goes down totally on both routers, traffic will go out through other ISP connection._" That will happen anyway. When a link to a BGP peer goes down, the routes from that peer are withdrawn.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

BGP multipath is for load balancing, not fail-over. In your topology, a basic (default) BGP configuration will already fail-over to one of the ISP2 links if both ISP1 links are down. If you'd also like to load balance between both ISP1 links (or both ISP2) links, by all means also configure BGP multipath. But it has nothing to do with fail-over.

You might find this helpful: https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos15.1/topics/concept/bgp-multipath-understanding.html